# There maybe a timestamping problem or this computer is too slow

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Does anyone get this output with gstreamer?

I am trying out gstreamer with rtp from my latptop to nvidia xavier

My sender pipeline is as such

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)I420' ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

My client pipeline is as such

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port=1234 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

I am getting the following output and my stream is slow and laggy too.

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is the CPU usage at these occasions? I have no experience with this platform - may its intention be to run most things on the GPU (like video decoding and display).

Try `sync=false` for the video sink. It may still be laggy but no frames will be thrown away. So maybe some more info can be gained by observing this pipeline.

What about using `autovideoconvert ! autovideosink` as a sink instead of using `xvimagesink`?

Consider using the `rtpbin` element instead of manually doing the RTP part. The bin does a lot of smart buffering etc that may help here.

And of course double check that the problem does not happen on the laptop encoder side..

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution has some issues. If GPU usage goes above 70-80% the picture will start lagging behind. The reason you need this setting in the first place is because the GPU is to week to process the pictures in time or is to busy.
Adding sync=false works fine in some cases, but can also lead to picture lagging behind several minutes. I improved this by adding queues with leaky=upstream, but then there is a lot of frame drops and the video will be choppy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may force force frequent I-frames on sender so that receiver can quickly display:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)I420' ! x264enc key-int-max=15 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

And on Jetson receiver side, use HW decoder (NVDEC):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=1234 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! xvimagesink
```